# Media query to shrink Bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, carousel

I am using Bootstrap version 4.0.0-beta and I am using the carousel function. I have configured it perfectly as to how I need it when I view it on my monitor. (1920 x 1200) but would like to change it's height depending on the users monitor, for example 1920 x 1080. I have given my Carousel a height of 32rem but would like to decrease that size if a user is on a smaller screen like I said. I believe a media query is what I need but I have tried and can't figure it out. Can anyone shine some light on this please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve it on my own. Just used this.

```
@media screen and (max-height: 1000px) {
.carousel-item {
height: 24rem;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the sample below and let me know if its worked.

```css
.img-responsive,
.thumbnail>img,
.thumbnail a>img,
.carousel-inner>.item>img,
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.carousel-inner {
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.carousel-caption {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 0 0 10px 25px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 15;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 25px 25px 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right {
  background-image: none;
}

.carousel-containers {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.carousel-containers {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #555;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-containers {
    padding: 1.5em 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 930px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-containers">
  <div class="container">

    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>


      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```